# Why am I unable to use a named range beginning with "Corona" in Excel charts?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm running into a ridiculous problem in Excel 2010 where I cannot seem to use a named range whose name begins with "Corona" in a chart. I've created a new workbook with a simplified version of the problem.

I have two worksheets which contain simple bar charts. I also have a sheet named "Data" with the following table:

```
      A     B
  +-------+---+
1 | ONE   | 1 |
2 | TWO   | 2 |
3 | THREE | 3 |
4 | FOUR  | 4 |
5 | FIVE  | 5 |
  +-------+---+
```

There are four named ranges in the workbook. The two "Names" ranges are identical and the two "Values" ranges are identical:

```
Brea_Names    : =Data!$A$1:$A$5
Corona_Names  : =Data!$A$1:$A$5
Brea_Values   : =Data!$B$1:$B$5
Corona_Values : =Data!$B$1:$B$5
```

On the Brea Chart sheet, if I highlight the series then press Enter, everything works fine. **On the Corona Chart sheet, if I highlight the series and change every "Brea_Names" to "Corona_Names", or change "Brea_Values" to "Corona_Values", I cannot press Enter. I don't get any error message; it's as though I didn't press Enter at all.**

I got around it by naming everything "ItsCorona" instead, but this still doesn't make sense to me. What's wrong with the name "Corona"?

The test file can be downloaded here: http://cl.ly/K4NJ/download/Book1.xlsx

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: It must be an Excel bug, I cannot reproduce this behaviour in Excel 2007 with your worksheet. Did you install all Office updates?

Comment: As far as I can tell, all Excel 2010 updates are applied.

Answer (score 4):

I **can** replicate this in Excel 2010. In fact, you have the same issue with any named range beginning with either a `C` or an `R`.

`C` and `R` are also the only single letter named ranges that you cannot have. It displays the following error when trying to create a named range called `C`: 
[image]

(By contrast a named range called `A` is fine)

I imagine you cannot name a named range `C` or `R` because of the `R1C1` reference style. And I wonder if it is Excel's use of this reference style that may be causing issues with any named range beginning with `C` or `R` in the chart source.

I would agree with Adam Ryczkowski's comment to your question that this looks like an Excel bug, and that the workaround is as you have done, to use a named range for the chart source that doesn't begin with an `R` or a `C`.

Comment: Ahh, that does make sense. Excellent use of psychic debugging.